# How to block ViewController Screen to not slide to sides

Tags: xcode, user-interface, storyboard, screen, viewcontroller

I've created a Screen on storyboard but the problem is that if I keeping pressing click the screen can slide to sides, I don't want this. How I block?

[image: GIF of case]

Comment: @dhilmathy how to do this?

Comment: I believe you're asking about adding inline image in question. For that you can refer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Yes, you alright. thank you.